# How to Skip the Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to skip or ignore in worksheet 2 if the value is already set as "**REFUNDED**" in Column R and then continue to look for other match in **Column G** and then set the value in **Column R**.

[image]

I tried to play around by changing some aspects in the code but it didn't work. Please help to fix this.

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (!(sheet.getSheetName() == "Backend" && range.getRow() > 1 && range.getColumn() == 17 && range.getValue() == "SOLD")) return;
  const srcId = range.offset(0, -16).getValue();
  const spreadsheetIdOfWorksheet2 = "1VEQs6h_vVrI1Hi8lMa9dvwxG0N7A_X-CwT5R9c"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID of "WorkSheet 2" here.
  const worksheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIdOfWorksheet2).getSheetByName("Advance");
  const dstValues = worksheet2.getRange("G2:G" + worksheet2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(srcId).findAll();
  if (dstValues.length > 0) {
     worksheet2.getRangeList(dstValues.map(r => r.offset(0, 11).getA1Notation())).setValue("Sold");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I want to skip or ignore in worksheet 2 if the value is already set as "REFUNDED" in Column R and then continue to look for other match in Column G and then set the value in Column R.` and `it didn't work`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? By the way, your sample image is the input situation?

Comment: Yes, Actually you helped me to solve the problem earlier to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880885/update-copy-the-cell-data-to-another-worksheet-based-on-id-match. There is another sheet called Worksheet ONE, when the Work Sheet 1 which we work on the status updates the work sheet two.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about the current issue and your goal of your question.

Comment: My goal is to skip the status row that contains REFUNDED in R Column in Work Sheet 2

Comment: Are you still not Clear? I can explain you in detail.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When your script is run, you want to skip the rows which have the value of "Refunded" at the column "R".

In this case, I would like to propose to modify the script in your if statement.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
const dstValues = worksheet2.getRange("G2:G" + worksheet2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(srcId).findAll();
if (dstValues.length > 0) {
   worksheet2.getRangeList(dstValues.map(r => r.offset(0, 11).getA1Notation())).setValue("Sold");
}
```

To:

```
const lastRow = worksheet2.getLastRow();
const dstValues = worksheet2.getRange("G2:G" + lastRow).createTextFinder(srcId).findAll();
if (dstValues.length > 0) {
  const temp = worksheet2.getRange("R2:R" + lastRow).createTextFinder("Refunded").matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map(e => e.getRow());
  worksheet2.getRangeList(dstValues.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (!temp.includes(r.getRow())) ar.push(r.offset(0, 11).getA1Notation());
    return ar;
  }, [])).setValue("Sold");
}
```

- `worksheet2.getLastRow()` can be declared only one time.
- In this modification, in the if statement, the row numbers which have the value of "Refunded" at the column "R" are retrieved, and the range list is created using the retrieved row numbers. By this, the rows which have the value of "Refunded" at the column "R" can be skipped.